# Sorting an ArrayList<String> with custom Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist, comparator

I am trying to sort an `ArrayList<String>` using custom `Comparator`. My requirement is that `XX` String should be the first String, others should follow natural ordering.

> I need : [XX, XX, 1, 5, 9, A, D, G, Q, Z]
>   What I am getting is [1, 5, 9, A, D, G, Q, Z, XX, XX]

Following is my code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Z");
        list.add("5");
        list.add("D");
        list.add("G");
        list.add("XX");     
        list.add("9");
        list.add("Q");
        list.add("XX");
        list.add("1");
        list.add("A");      
        Collections.sort(list, new CustomComparator());     
        System.out.println(list);       
    }
}
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {      
        if(o2.equals("XX")) {
            return -1;
        }       
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }   
}
```

**EDIT**: if i change comparator logic to:

```
@Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {      
        if(o2.equals("XX")) {
            return 1;
        }       
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
```

I am getting :

> [1, XX, 9, A, Q, XX, 5, D, G, Z]

Please let me know how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this comparator implementation:

```
@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {      
    if(o2.equals("XX")) {
        return o1.equals("XX") ? 0 : 1;
    } else if (o1.equals("XX")) {
        return -1;
    }
    return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```

**Reason:** Beyond the question when to use -1 or 1 it is important to guarantee a clear order for all possible tuples of o1 and o2, see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-):

[...]
The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y. (This implies that compare(x, y) must throw an exception if and only if compare(y, x) throws an exception.)

The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: ((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0)) implies compare(x, z)>0.
[...]

Comment: congratulations, your solution is only valid one

Comment: @nikis Thank you, I am used to such comparators because my employer often ask for exotic and overly complex comparison strategies, this here is just very simplified ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Concise way to write the method:

```
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    if (o1.equals(o2)) return 0;
    if (o1.equals("XX")) return -1;
    return (o2.equals("XX")) ? 1 : o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```