# Sorting ArrayList not affecting to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to sort `ArrayList` on the basis of `String` actually I have numbers in `""`, like this: `"4000"`

I have written code to sort arraylist on the basis of price, but whenever i do tap on button it is not affecting to my ListView... why ?

I am following [this](http://javatechig.com/java/core-java/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-in-java) tutorial....

This is how my `JSON` looks:

```
{
"locations": [
{
"name": "Office",
"price": "4,00,000"
},
{
"name": "Work",
"price": "1,20,000"
}
]
}
```

`Model` class:

```
public class Locations {

    private String name;
    private String price;

    public Locations() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Locations(String name, String price) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

`LocationsActivity.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_locations);
    actorsList = new ArrayList<Locations>();
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute(" ");

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new LocationsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.adapter_locations, actorsList);

    btnHTL = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHTL);
    btnHTL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Collections.sort(actorsList, new Comparator<Locations>(){
                  public int compare(Locations obj1, Locations obj2)
                  {
                      // ascending
                      return (Integer)(arg1.price).compareTo(arg2.price);
                  }
                });
            }
        }); 

    btnLTH = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLTH);
    btnLTH.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Collections.sort(actorsList, new Comparator<Locations>(){
                  public int compare(Locations obj1, Locations obj2)
                  {
                      // descending
                      return (Integer)(arg2.price).compareTo(arg1.price);
                  }
                }); 
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: So what's the question? I don't get what you're trying to do. By reading your code the first thing i would suggest you is to process the result in your onPostExecute, not in your doInBackground, just left doInBackground for background network operations

Comment: how to filter records - simply want to show records based on price High to Low and Low to High

Comment: sort your arraylist by price.

Comment: @DivyangMetalia exactly this is what i want to know !'

Comment: I believe this might help http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/ You have to define an order to your array based on what it contains and what you want to order, so you can sort it by using the sort() function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an ArrayList<String> with custom Comparator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296627/sorting-an-arrayliststring-with-custom-comparator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button asc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.asc);
        Button desc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.desc);
        final ArrayList<Location> actorsList = new ArrayList<Location>();

        Location loc = new Location();
        loc.setName("1");
        loc.setPrice("4000");
        actorsList.add(loc);

        loc = new Location();
        loc.setName("2");
        loc.setPrice("8000");
        actorsList.add(loc);

        loc = new Location();
        loc.setName("3");
        loc.setPrice("1000");
        actorsList.add(loc);

        loc = new Location();
        loc.setName("4");
        loc.setPrice("16000");
        actorsList.add(loc);

        asc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Collections.sort(actorsList, new Comparator<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Location arg1, Location arg2) {
                        Integer obj1 = new Integer(arg1.getPrice().replace(",",""));
                        Integer obj2 = new Integer(arg2.getPrice().replace(",",""));
                        return (Integer) (obj1).compareTo(obj2);
                    }
                });

                for (int i = 0; i < actorsList.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("monika 1233"
                            + actorsList.get(i).getPrice());
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: i want to implement both the functionalities, a button to show list High to Low and another to show list Low to High

Comment: but I want to implement sort functionality on click of buttons, see my code above

Comment: yes thats what creat a method in pojo class and that tell whether u want asc or dec order sorting

Comment: so in compare method above provide if else hence that will give u sorting data

Comment: best to do is : always sort in asc and do   Arrays.sort(data, Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: @Moon price is string dear ..parse to int

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59100/discussion-between-moon-and-adcom).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29), which takes a comparator in argument. In the comparator you will define what you want to compare (here, the price).

Answer (score 0):

I added code for `int` sorting:

```
Collections.sort(actorsList, new Comparator<Locations>() {
    public int compare(Locations user1, Locations user2) {
        return user1.price.compareTo(user2.price);
    }
});
```

And `implement` `Comparable` method in your `Location` model:

```
Locations implements Comparable<Locations>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make class like this:

```
class PriceSort implements Comparator<location> {
    @Override
    public int compare(location cr1, location cr2) {

          long l1 = Integer.parseInt(cr1.getPrice());
          long l2 = Integer.parseInt(cr2.getPrice());
          return Long.compare(l1, l2);

    }
}
```

And call like:

```
Collections.sort(actorsList, new PriceSort());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort the list by price, use custom [comparator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm). If you want filter the list based on any search term, use [Filterable interface](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html)